# Accessing resources in a Java[Maven] Project

Tags: java, maven, resources, classloader

Once and for all somebody, explain how to correctly access resources like **DATABASE**, **HTML** files and so on.

Suppose my Maven JavaFX project looks something like this (check the image).

[image: http://s30.postimg.org/lacoynzv5/image.png]

It has it's

> src/main/java

and

> src/main/resources

in the Build Path

[image: Build path]

Inside resources I have a folder with a **database** and a folder with a **html file**.

Here is how I access the database and it works when I run it inside the IDE, but doesn't work after packaging or running the .exe file after **mvn native**

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/DB/SeeYourUse.sqlite");
```

Here is how I access my **HTML file** to use it in a **WebView**

```
String url = Main.class.getResource("/HTML/help.html").toExternalForm();  
webEngine.load(url);
```

And it DOES work inside the IDE (jfx:run and running as java application as well), but not a chance to run it after the deployment.

Here is the error I get when I run it and log it.

```
java.sql.SQLException: path to 'src/main/resources/DB/SeeYourUse.sqlite': 'E:\Programming\Java\Work\SeeYourUse\target\jfx\native\SeeYourUse-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\app\src' does not exist
```

The **QUESTION** is:
**How do I properly load the database and the HTML to be able to use it at maximum?**

Answer (score 2):

src/main/resources is copied into your jar file directly, as is target/classes. You are able to access resources by `class.getResource(String name)` that returns the URL of a resource, and also `Class.getResourceAsStream(String name)` that will open a stream. But, in your specific case of a database, I would NOT put resources in a jar file as a jdbc driver loads database files directly from filesystem. You should extract a database to an external location by opening a stream to it and writing it to an external directory, at least if it does not exist already.

As for html files, you can retrieve URL's in case of such static resources and use them directly as noted above. Note however that the web engine will be unable to use other resources referenced from a html file, unless you can replace the logic that it uses to find them. In a case of such things, I would even extract the html file and all files it depends on into a temp location.

Comment: What I said applies in case of a flat directory structure too, not necessarily packed into a jar file.

Comment: So do you mean I don't need to put resources inside the build path? Or just to keep the database somewhere outside (which, by the way, works, but doesn't seem like a good decision).

Comment: After deployment, it is normal that your resources are in the same directory as your classes. this is usually packed into a jar file isn't it?

Comment: Well, after using the command jfx:native, maven gives me two folders. /app and /native. I used to run the application as .exe. 
I definitely need some tutorials or documentation on this. Do you have some useful links?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but you can try reading about javapackager. still, I believe your resources *will* be packed like I said. I guarantee that your current app won't work as java application if you move it's jar file somewhere outside of the maven project structure. but html should load properly, and you didn't complain about html not loading, did you?

Comment: I reused the command jfx:native but my database is (jdbc:sqlite:SeeYourUse.sqlite) in the main directory.    
I moved the whole directory containing folders /app, /runtime and the .exe to the other place and as expected, it started and the things related to the database work properly, but the window containing the webview doesn't open, meaning it has an error.

EVEN THOUGH I run it with getResource

Comment: /lib with a lot of libraries, 
my database,
SeeYourUse-1.0.0.cfg, 
SeeYourUse-1.0.0-jfx.jar.

Comment: resources should be loaded from the jar file, check if the jar file contains resources too

Comment: The jar file contains all the compiled classes and all the resources, as expected

Comment: so: the html file should actually load (path like html/whatever), database will not load as sqlite reads from folders, not from Class.getResource/etc, so I would extract the database and then use it.

Comment: What do you mean under "I would extract and then use it". What certainly should I do?

Comment: Use `Class.getResourceAsStream()` to open the database file, and write it either to a tmp directory if your database is not to be modified, or to a permanent data directory for example .myprogramname in the user's home directory, if you intent to modify it. then you do not extract again if it exists.

Comment: Still getting null pointer exception when trying to access the html file. Maybe I'm not oppening it right?

Comment: well, maybe remove the / from the beginning to the path to it?

Comment: If I remove it, It won't even work at IDE stage and the logger writes the same null pointer exception when I run the jar

Comment: Suddenly, I changed "help.html" to "Help.html" and it worked :D
But...without css though

Comment: okay. if the path to the html file is good in relation to the root of the jar file, then getResource should work returning an URL. can the web engine load from an input stream or equivalent? I would prefer that approach if that is possible. You can also extract the html file to a temporary location.

Comment: I have edited/expanded the answer to make it easier to find what we were talking about.

Comment: Okay, the html now loads, but I have a problem with loading the css and images now

Comment: Note the answer that I have modified. webengine probably does not load resources using Class.getResource family, so it has no chance of finding images/etc. Check if you can influence a way in which resources are loaded in web engine, if not, then you would have to extract all htmls, css and images to a common directory.

Comment: Extract using InputStream as well?

Comment: Probably, but this still seems ugly doesn't it? first thing to do is to check if web engine can be told how to find resources. if not, then extracting like I said seems to be your only option

Comment: Ohh. I have read that javafx webengine supports jar urls. So it should actually work.

Comment: That is, loading of relative resources could work if you were loading from the URL as urls going inside jars are supported.

Comment: So how should I place inside the html a image?
src="file:Images/example.jpg"?
jar:HTML/Images/example.jpg?

Comment: It probably should be a relative url like src="images/xxx"

Comment: This would work if I could somehow tell the webengine where my resources are, but how can I do it?

Comment: It knows where the html was loaded from, so I actually believe it should also be able to resolve relative paths. If not, I am not a javafx developer and can't really help you further with this.